# How do I get xml a specific element content using Android XmlPullParser

Tags: android, xml, xmlpullparser

I am using XmlPullParse to parse a xml like this:

```
<root>
    <node description="this is a node">
        <number key="ID">0</number>
        <number key="room">3324</number>
        <desc key="title">software engineer</desc>
        <desc key="job">eat donuts</desc>
    </node>
</root>
```

How do I get "eat donuts" to a String?

right now my code is like:

```
String expectedResult;

while (xrp.getEventType() != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
  if (xrp.getEventType() == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) {
      String name = xrp.getName();
          if (name.equals("desc") && xrp.getAttributeValue(0).equals("job")){
    //I can get here
      if (xrp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
         //I can NOT get here
          expectedResult=xrp.getText(); 
      } 
      }
   } 
 xrp.next(); 
}
```

when debugging my code can reach "//I can get here", meaning I found the line by using

```
name.equals("desc") && xrp.getAttributeValue(0).equals("job"
```

but I can not reach "I can NOT get here", meaning somehow

```
(xrp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
```

is wrong.
How can I correct my code and get the String using getText() and assign it to expectedResult?
Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to do a `xrp.next()` there so the parser can advance to the text.

Comment: Yes. That is it. I will happy to mark the answer if you put it in the answer section.